# Правильно ли построено предложение "А что, смешно"?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

Нужно ли его разделить на два предложения и поставить вопросительный знак?
Если оно построено правильно, то чем является конструкция "а что"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***А что, смешно?***

1. ***А что*** не входит в состав предложения, это **сочетание междометного характера,** которое относится к группе **вопросительно-восклицательных слов.**

Розенталь, [§ 29. Утвердительные, отрицательные и вопросительно-восклицательные слова](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=129):

Слова ***что, а что, что же***, обозначающие вопросы, и слова ***как, как же, что же,*** выражающие удивление, подтверждение, согласие и т. п., за которыми следует **предложение**, раскрывающее их конкретный смысл (после них делается пауза), отделяются запятой: ***Что,** ему лет двадцать пять, не больше?* (Л. Т.); ***А что,** если он прячется в глубине лесов?* (Каз.); ***Как,** разве всё тут? Шутите!* (П.)...

2. Парный вариант

*Тебе, я вижу, смешно? **А что смешно**?*